# How to force CSS to be displayed on empty element following whitespace

Tags: html, css

I've got an empty element that appears at the end of a list of children.  The purpose of the element is to display the CSS border that I have assigned:

```
.test {
    border-left:solid 1px Black;
}
```

And then the HTML looks something like this:

```
<p>This is a test.<span class='test'></span></p>
```

Normally this displays fine, but if the previous element is text which ends in a space, the element is no longer rendered:

```
<p>This is a test. <span class='test'></span></p>
```

I've created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4AG6r/) which demonstrates this.  I expect both lines to have a vertical bar (from the CSS) at the end, but only the second one does.

What's going on here?  How can I get both lines to display the CSS border?

Comment: Do you want to do:
<p><span class='test'>This is a test.</span></p>??

Comment: No, I don't want anything in the span, although this suggests a possible workaround - for the above case I would have to change border-left to border-right, but this adds a special condition I have to check in the logic which generates the HTML, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: A nonbreakable space seems to get the desired results, although I can't tell you why it wasn't working in the first place. http://jsfiddle.net/4AG6r/6/

Comment: I see vertical bars for both.

Comment: @x23 Aha... maybe it's a browser bug?  I see both bars in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Maybe. I'm seeing them with IE.

Comment: Seems like I've had an issue like this before and I just put a `|` character between the beginning and ending `span` tags.

Comment: @MattCremeens Unfortunately I'm relying on the border and the spacing doesn't work out to allow me to put anything in the span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the default your `span` has only 1px width. This might cause a rendering problem. Adding `&nbsp;` fixes your problem:

```
<p>This is a test 1.<span class='test'>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p>This is a test 2.<span class='test'>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Alternatively you could just add a margin to your `span`, since inline elements can't have a fixed width (Thanks Michael):

```
.test {
    border-left:solid 1px Black;
    margin: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: I like the width approach, but it doesn't seem to actually work.

Comment: Guess I was wrong. Inline elements like the span can't have a fixed width. But they can have a margin. I'll update my answer

Comment: Looks like a 1px wide transparent image in the `SPAN` is sufficient to make the border show up.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>This is a test. <span class='test'>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

or even better:

```
.test:after {
    content: "\00a0";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4AG6r/13/

All the span needs is some content to avoid browser specific render issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of your p element to be only wide enough to hold what's in it (e.g., 100px) and then use `border-right` in the test class. So,

```
p {
  width: 100px;
}

.test {
  border-right: solid 1px Black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your text information inside `<span>` ... `</span>` and change the side of you css border.

http://jsfiddle.net/L2Fbg/

```
.test {
    border-right:solid 1px Black;
}

<p><span class='test'>This is a test.</span></p>
<p><span class='test'>This is a test. </span></p>
```